# Can't build or install React Native app after installing React Navigation

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, react-navigation

I've just started building my first React Native app with minimal success. I've built my boilerplate code but now I want to add a separate screen to it. Cue React Navigation.

Having tried twice to install the module, I've not had much luck. I used both [Facebook's documentation](https://reactnative.dev/docs/navigation) and the [Getting Started](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/hello-react-navigation) guide from React Navigation themselves. Still no luck.

The error I get is something to do with the build.gradle file in my android folder. As per the Getting Started guide, I did add two lines into my dependencies area but this doesn't appear to have had any effect.

The error message is as follow:

```
Could not compile build file: 
'C:\Users\USERNAME\Documents\ReactNative\WasteAway\android\app\build.gradle\'
> startup failed
General error during semantic analysis: Unsupported class file major version 57
```

My dependencies in the `build.gradle` file are as follows:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-rc01'
    implementation 'androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.1.0-alpha02'

    if (enableHermes) {
        def hermesPath = "../../node_modules/hermes-engine/android/";
        debugImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-debug.aar")
        releaseImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-release.aar")
    } else {
        implementation jscFlavor
    }
}
```

Am I missing something obvious here or have I skipped a step on the tutorials? I can't see where I'm going wrong here, folks. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please write full gradle log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering this since I've been advised on the solution: 
It looks like it was the version of the JDK that I was using which was causing problems. Strangely enough, I was using too new a version that was notoriously buggy. Uninstalling and reverting JDK1.8 solved my issues. Explanation [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/26625#issuecomment-541368275).